# Time complexity of copying a string

Tags: c++, time-complexity

does this invoke the copy constructor and what is the time complexity of this code? I read in a book somewhere that this uses the copy constructor and had a really bad time complexity.

```cpp
string tmp = "thisisanexample";
string current =  "";
for(int i = 0; i < tmp.size(); ++i){
     current = current + tmp[i]; //does this require the copy constructor to copy the stuff in tmp?
}
```

Comment: At least the C++ version using `std::string` is more efficient than the C version: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/

Comment: Time complexity is O(n) depends on size of string (but complexity isn't your question, it is how much time does each step cost). And yes new strings are allocated in each run of the loop.  Consider using `std::stringstream` and then converting back to a string after the loop. (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str)

Comment: That's an infinite loop. You should choose your code example more carefully.

Comment: @john right!  So does that make it O(∞)?

Comment: what is the time complexity now? I edited it so it is no longer a infinite loop. what is the overall time complexity of the code and what is the time complexity of just the line inside the for loop where we copy current and add a letter

Comment: @superfly This variation `current += tmp[i]` is O(N) for sure. One question is whether an optimizing compiler could translate your code into my variation. I don't know the answer to that, although I believe it would be legal for one to do so. Assuming no such optimizing goes on then your code is O(N^2) because of the construction of the temporary string from `current + tmp[i]` and the assignment of that temporary string back to `current`.

Comment: @MarkRansom Since the run time of an infinite loop does not depend on the input data, I think a case can be made for O(1), followed by a lesson in how low time complexity does not guarantee low run times. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is quadratic in the length of the original string because `current + tmp[i];` returns a new string by-value each time, but must keep a copy of the old value in `current` as well, since it is unknown at that point whether `current`'s value will still be needed. Of course that is optimizations by a sufficiently clever compiler notwithstanding.

To make this efficient with linear complexity in the length of the original string add `std::move` to tell the compiler that you don't need to preserve the original value of `current`, so that its memory can be reused:

```
current = std::move(current) + tmp[i];
```

or even better, just use copy assignment of `std::string` which probably is even faster as it knows exactly how much memory to allocate up-front and doesn't need to do any of the several move operations involved in the line above.

```
current = tmp;
```

---

There is no direct copy constructor call in the shown code though. `current = std::move(current) + tmp[i];` with or without `std::move` uses only `operator+` (but different overloads) and the move assignment operator of `std::string` as `operator+` returns by-value either way.

However the lvalue overload of `operator+` is specified to behave as if making a copy of the original string, which uses the copy constructor, adding the new character to the end of it and then returning it.

Comment: `operator +=` would be better than `std::move`.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I tried to show the (in some sense) minimal change required to make it linear. As I mentioned, to copy a string the loop shouldn't be there at all. Just use `std::string`s assignment.

Comment: Yeah, but sometimes assignment isn't an option. Maybe you want to concatenate or only copy parts of a string (although then a string_view + substr works great). You could also mention `std::copy` and `std::move (algorithms)` for alternatives that work on most containers.